# How to find the callerStatus and calleeStatus for RingCentral calls?

Tags: phone-call, calllog, ringcentral, ringout

How do I get call status for past calls?

I want to get the `callerStatus` and `calleeStatus` status which I see in the RingOut Status API response but I'm not sure what to use for the `ringOutId` in the URL path:

https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#RingOut-getRingOutCallStatus

**Request**

GET /restapi/v1.0/account/400162076008/extension/400162076009/ring-out/Y3MxNzE4NDkyODg0NDM5MDJAMTAuNjIuMjkuMzM

**Response**

```
HTTP 200 OK

{
    "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/400162076008/extension/400162076009/ring-out/2",
    "id" : "Y3MxNzE4NDkyODg0NDM5MDJAMTAuNjIuMjkuMzM",
    "status" : {
      "callStatus" : "Success",
      "callerStatus" : "Success",
      "calleeStatus" : "Success"
    }
}
```

When making a RingOut Status call without a `ringOutId`, I was hoping to get a list of calls, but I get the following error instead:

```
Resource for parameter [ringOutId] is not found
```

What do I use for `ringOutId`? How can I get the `callerStatus` and `calleeStatus` for calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### RingOut Active Call Status

The RingOut Status API is only used when making phone calls via RingOut. The `ringOutId` is returned in the response for the Make RingOut API. It also only returns status while the call is in progress and a short time later, after which, it will return a 404.

API Ref: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#RingOut-makeRingOutCall

#### RingOut Historical Call Status

To get call status for historical calls, use the Call Log API. By default, the service will return status for the overall call in the `result` property. To get status on individual parties on the call, known as legs, use the Detailed Call Log API. The following URLs are available:

**Company Call Log (all users)**

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log?view=Detailed
```

https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Call-Log-loadCompanyCallLog

**User Extension Call Log**

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/call-log?view=Detailed
```

https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Call-Log-loadUserCallLog

With the detailed view, you will receive a response with the `legs` property, which is an array of call log records also known as a [Call Detail Records (CDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_detail_record). An example record is shown below. Each call in the `legs` array has a `result` property. `result` is used instead of status because the call log only lists completed calls. Each leg has a `legType` property that can be used to identify the caller and callee.

For example, `legType` can be set to:

- `RingOutClientToCaller`
- `RingOutClientToSubscriber`

`RingOutClientToSubscriber` can be used for the `calleeStatus`. This gives us:

- `callerStatus` = `leg.result` where `leg.legType == 'RingOutClientToCaller'`
- `calleeStatus` = `leg.result` where `leg.legType == 'RingOutClientToSubscriber'`

> **Note:** It's possible for a CDR to only have one leg. This can happen if the `result` is `Busy`. In RingOut, if one party is busy, it can be an optimization to not call the other party. Many times, our customers will use RingOut to call their employee first, and if the employee picks up, then call the customer. If the employee isn't there, there's no reason to call the customer and have them listen to a busy tone.

Here's a response call log record example:

```
{
  "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/727097016/extension/727097016/call-log/L6HbCN6tB1nyDUA?view=Detailed",
  "id": "L6HbCN6tB1nyDUA",
  "sessionId": "575838550017",
  "startTime": "2018-11-22T08:42:05.500Z",
  "duration": 19,
  "type": "Voice",
  "direction": "Outbound",
  "action": "RingOut PC",
  "result": "Call connected",
  "to": {
    "phoneNumber": "+12125550111",
    "name": "Daenerys Targaryen",
  },
  "from": {
    "phoneNumber": "+16505550101",
    "name": "John Snow"
  },
  "extension": {
    "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/727097016/extension/727097016",
    "id": 727097016
  },
  "transport": "PSTN",
  "lastModifiedTime": "2018-11-22T08:42:30.007Z",
  "billing": {
    "costIncluded": 0.0,
    "costPurchased": 0.0
  },
  "legs": [
    {
      "startTime": "2018-11-22T08:42:05.257Z",
      "duration": 20,
      "type": "Voice",
      "direction": "Outbound",
      "action": "RingOut PC",
      "result": "Call connected",
      "to": {
        "phoneNumber": "+16505550101",
        "name": "John Snow"
      },
      "from": {
        "phoneNumber": "+12125550111",
        "name": "Daenerys Targaryen",
      },
      "extension": {
        "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/727097016/extension/727097016",
        "id": 727097016
      },
      "transport": "PSTN",
      "billing": {
        "costIncluded": 0.0,
        "costPurchased": 0.0
      },
      "legType": "RingOutClientToSubscriber"
    },
    {
      "startTime": "2018-11-22T08:42:05.500Z",
      "duration": 19,
      "type": "Voice",
      "direction": "Outbound",
      "action": "RingOut PC",
      "result": "Call connected",
      "to": {
        "phoneNumber": "+12125550111",
        "name": "Daenerys Targaryen",
      },
      "from": {
        "phoneNumber": "+16505550101",
        "name": "John Snow"
      },
      "extension": {
        "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/727097016/extension/727097016",
        "id": 727097016
      },
      "transport": "PSTN",
      "legType": "RingOutClientToCaller",
      "master": true
    }
  ]
},
```

> **Note:** In the detailed call log example, the `to` and `from` for the `RingOutClientToCaller` leg coincide with the `to` and `from` for the overall call, while they are reversed for the `RingOutClientToSubscriber` leg to the callee. This is because the callee will be connect with the caller, whose number is in the `to` property from their perspective.

Answer (score 0):

you can call
[https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/active-calls](https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/%7E/active-calls)
this endpoint get all active call details
please see
https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/voice/finding-active-calls